# Is a photo that is in the public domain in US also in the public domain in other countries?

Tags: public-domain

I want to use a photograph that is in the public domain in the United States. However, I would be sending a document with this photograph around entities in Europe. I know that just because something is in the public domain in the United States, that doesn't mean that it is in the public domain in other countries. Can I use this photograph or not and what decides this?

This is the photo in question:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rowing_at_the_1988_Summer_Olympics.JPEG

The "Permission" field in the "Summary" section details what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under US law, the particular work is not protected by copyright, being a government work. Therefore, an infringement suit in the US would go nowhere. Under the [Berne Convention Article 7(8)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/treaties/berne/7.html),

> the term shall be governed by the legislation of the country where
>   protection is claimed; however, unless the legislation of that country
>   otherwise provides, the term shall not exceed the term fixed in the
>   country of origin of the work

This is acknowledged via EU [Directive 2006/116/EC](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2006:372:0012:0018:EN:PDF), Article 7:

> Where the country of origin of a work, within the meaning of the Berne
>   Convention, is a third country, and the author of the work is not a
>   Community national, the term of protection granted by the Member
>   States shall expire on the date of expiry of the protection granted in
>   the country of origin of the work, but may not exceed the term laid
>   down in Article 1.

So unless there is a special provision in the country in question, the shorter of the protection-time of the country of origin and that of the country of lawsuit  prevails, i.e. zero in this instance. No jurisdiction in Europe appears to have created a special exception to the effect that government works are subject to copyright protection.

Comment: A German court ruled that the rule of the shorter term doesn't apply to US works, as per the copyright treaty between the two nations signed in 1892.